# Cost of SORT is slowing down my query

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-statement, query-performance

PostgreSQL 7.4 (Yep upgrading)

So in my WHERE condition I have this

```
AND CASE
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text 
        OR "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 4) = '123'::text 
        OR "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 5) = '5555'::text 
        OR "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 6) = '44444'::text 
        OR "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '99'::text 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Alternate syntax but no change in Cost

```
AND CASE
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text THEN 1
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 4) = '123'::text THEN 1
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 5) = '5555'::text THEN 1
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 6) = '44444'::text THEN 1
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '99'::text THEN 1    
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Looking for a Cost effective way to limit the results by the start of a string. So if the string starts with 01, 123, 5555, 44444 or 99 add it to the result set.

Any thoughts?

Note: the FieldID is indexed
Viewing the Explain data to see the bottle necks in the query, when adding the above code is when the cost of the Sort goes way up and slows the return of the data set/results.

Output from Explain:

```
Sort (cost=88716.84..88719.89 rows=822 width=64)
```

there is a ton more as the query is complex but if I remove the part of the code the Sort cost goes way down

Comment: a the prefixes (`'01'`, `'123'`, etc) known at schema definition time or are they dependent on the individual queries?

Comment: it's a data field that contains an integer

Comment: I mean the prefixes always the same for every query, or do you look for different sets of prefixes in each query?

Comment: sry yes, I only need to look for those prefixes, they will not change but could be added to in the future. So more of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just filtering by the starting chars, you can use `like` with no problem and it will just use an index.

```
AND (t."FieldID"::text LIKE '01%' OR 
     t."FieldID"::text LIKE '123%' OR 
     t."FieldID"::text LIKE '5555%' OR
     t."FieldID"::text LIKE '44444%' OR
     t."FieldID"::text LIKE '99%')
```

Comment: would this also be faster then a RegEx? t."FieldID" ~'^01'

Comment: @Phill, in this example yes, it's hard to use an index with regex. But you could build a regex index in other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

you might get some traction by defining expression indexes that match the query;  something like

```
CREATE INDEX t_fieldid_prefix_3 ON t (("substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 3)))
CREATE INDEX t_fieldid_prefix_4 ON t (("substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 4)))
CREATE INDEX t_fieldid_prefix_5 ON t (("substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 5)))
CREATE INDEX t_fieldid_prefix_6 ON t (("substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 6)))
```

If you're always looking for the same prefixes, include the whole thing in the index:

```
CREATE INDEX t_fieldid_prefix ON t((CASE
    WHEN "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text 
        OR "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 4) = '123'::text 
        OR "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 5) = '5555'::text 
        OR "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 6) = '44444'::text 
        OR "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '99'::text 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END))
```

Comment: would something like this work even if FieldID is already index?

Comment: Looking at the [syntax for 7.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-createindex.html) you might have to define a function to support the latter case, since it doesn't appear to allow arbitrary expressions.

Comment: the index for FieldID won't accelerate filtering on complex expressions like `substring()`; but an expression index can allow the query planner to look for matching rows directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether this is supported by your ancient version, but you could try to create an index on the sort expression to see if that improves the query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_case ON the_table (
  (CASE
      WHEN substring("FieldID", 0, 3) = '01' THEN 1
      WHEN substring("FieldID", 0, 4) = '123' THEN 1
      WHEN substring("FieldID", 0, 5) = '5555' THEN 1
      WHEN substring("FieldID", 0, 6) = '44444' THEN 1
      WHEN substring("FieldID", 0, 3) = '99' THEN 1    
      ELSE 0
  END));
```

With a current version I'm pretty sure this could be used to improve the ORDER BY step

Comment: would something like this work even if FieldID is already index?

Comment: @Phil: yes that will work, because the (complete) index expression is different.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often this sort of query is run, and also on how much data there is, you might consider calculating some of this external to the query and adding extra columns to use as indexes only. The same way a data warehouse denormalizes to speed up reporting queries.

Comment: about 500,000 records and it's a heavily used database with lots of indexes. The query will run multiple times throughout the day which is why I'm looking for a performance tweak