# SQL Performance, What executes faster in the SELECT and WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance

UPDATE: Crap! it's not an integer it's character varying(10)

Executing the query like this uses the index

```
SELECT t."FieldID"
FROM table t
WHERE t."FieldID" = '0123456789'
```

But does not use the index if I execute this

```
SELECT t."FieldID"
FROM table t
WHERE t."FieldID" LIKE '01%'
```

or this

```
SELECT t."FieldID"
FROM table t
WHERE "substring"(t."FieldID", 0, 3) = '01'
```

also this

```
SELECT t."FieldID"
FROM table t
WHERE t."FieldID" ~ '^01'
```

My index looks like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fieldid_index
  ON "table"
  USING btree
  ("FieldID");
```

Running PostgreSQL 7.4 (Yep Upgrading)

I'm optimizing my query and wanted to know if there is any performance gains using one of the three types of expressions in either the SELECT or WHERE clause in the statement.

NOTE: The query that executes with these style of constraints returns around 200,000 records

Example Data is a *character varying(10)*: `0123456789` and it is indexed as well

**1. (Substring)**

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text         
    THEN 'Found Match'::text
    ELSE NULL::text
END AS matching_group
```

**2. (Like)**

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN t."FieldID"::text LIKE '01%'         
    THEN 'Found Match'::text
    ELSE NULL::text
END AS matching_group
```

**3. (RegEx)**

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN t."FieldID" ~ '^01'         
    THEN 'Found Match'::text
    ELSE NULL::text
END AS matching_group
```

Also is there any performance advantages using one over the other in the WHERE clause?

**1. (Substring)**

```
WHERE CASE
    WHEN "substring"(t."FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text         
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

**2. (Like)**

```
WHERE CASE
    WHEN t."FieldID"::text LIKE '01%'         
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

**3. (RegEx)**

```
WHERE CASE
    WHEN t."FieldID" ~ '^01'         
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```

Would using one option in the SELECT and a different option in the WHERE clause improve performance?

Comment: Can't you look at the execution plan and see which (if any) give you a seek rather than a scan?

Comment: Using any of the options in a single query only give me scan, how do I invoke the seek? Result set is around 200K

Comment: I've not much of a clue on Postges I'm afraid. What if you try `WHERE YourCol >= '01' AND YourCol < '02'` out of interest?

Comment: To avoid Scans you might want to look into creating some more indexes. You can create quite complicated indexes. Have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/indexes.html to see if there's anything that will help you.

Comment: Doesn't work as 0123456789 is not between 01 and 02 but I do see what you were trying to do

Comment: Er, '0123456789' certainly is between '01' and '02'; try it `select '01234' between '01' and '02';`

Comment: @TekenMacGuy you example does work but if I use it like this nothing is returned:  SELECT t."FieldID" FROM table t WHERE t."FieldID" BETWEEN '01' AND '02'

Comment: @Phil - I assumed you were dealing with strings? If not that might explain why none of these can use an index.

Comment: `0123456789` is **not** an integer because an integer does not have leading zeros (`123456789` is an integer value)

Comment: @Martin Smith: The regex '^01' sure looks like a string. Integers don't have leading zeroes.

Comment: ugh.. updated question as it's not an integer, character varying(10)

Comment: That would make the range-query (Martin Smith, above) possible again.

Comment: @MartinSmith could you add the BETWEEN as a answer as this helped with the index issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server the version with `LIKE '01%'` would be sargable. It actually converts these `LIKE` queries without leading wildcards to range queries.

The execution plan shows the seek predicate as being `YourCol >= '01' AND YourCol < '02'` perhaps a similar sort of rewrite could help in Postgresql?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think that someone who creates this kind of a problem should not be allowed to use the word "performance". Restrictions (like those in the WHERE clause) on the **text representation** of the contents of a numeric field (maybe even a keyfield) indicate bad design, IMHO.

If this were my data, I would add a flagfield to the record, indicating wanted / not wanted in query xyz. One could even put it into a separate table. I prefer adding a (redundant?) column to creating an entire index based on GW-basic-substring rubbish.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have also updated my question in an effort to clarify things a little more

Comment: The original query was even uglier. This topic is not about performance; is is about (lack of) design. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408499/cost-of-sort-is-slowing-down-my-query

Comment: understandable, not my design just trying to make a project work to what they have spec'ed out

Answer (score 3):

The two things that have the most effect are indexing and sargability. *Sargability* means using an expression that can take advantage of an index. You measure their effect by using

```
ANALYZE your_first_table;
-- ANALYZE other tables used in this query.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT ...
```

See the docs for [Examining index usage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-examine.html).

You might be able to take advantage of [indexes on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html) or [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-partial.html).  PostgreSQL 7.4 supports both indexes on expressions and partial indexes. For testing, you can [discourage certain kinds of query plans](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE). (Also in 7.4.)

An expression-based index that might work for you:

```
create index firsttwochars
on your-table-name (substring(your-column-name from 1 for 2));
```

But you still need to test your queries to see whether they actually use the index. (Whether they're *sargable*.)  This one might work.

```
select your-column-name 
from your-table-name 
where substring(your-column-name from 1 for 2) = '01'
```

Query plan without the index on the first two characters. (My test table uses random text-only usernames, which is why I searched on 'ab' instead of '01'.)

```
Seq Scan on substring  (cost=0.00..205.00 rows=50 width=11) (actual time=0.315..4.377 rows=14 loops=1)
  Filter: (substring((username)::text, 1, 2) = 'ab'::text)
Total runtime: 4.414 ms
```

Query plan *with* the index on the first two characters.

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on substring  (cost=4.36..37.61 rows=14 width=11) (actual time=0.036..0.056 rows=14 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (substring((username)::text, 1, 2) = 'ab'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on firsttwochars  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=14 width=0) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=14 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (substring((username)::text, 1, 2) = 'ab'::text)
Total runtime: 0.098 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have also updated my question in an effort to clarify things a little more

Comment: @Phill Pafford: PostgreSQL 7.4 supports both partial indexes and expression-based indexes, so you should be able to improve performance immediately. (I thought expression-based indexes were added in 8.something; I was wrong about that.)

Answer (score 1):

In the select list, there will probably not be much difference between the three expressions.  It's all CPU time.

For the `WHERE` clause, you could add an expression index such as

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON sometable ((
CASE
    WHEN "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text         
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
));
```

but the selectivity of such a Boolean index will likely be bad enough to not interest the planner.  It would be better to rewrite the `WHERE` clause to just

```
WHERE "substring"("FieldID"::text, 0, 3) = '01'::text
```

and then index that.

For the `LIKE` and regex cases you could consider a `text_pattern_ops` index as well; see the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/indexes-opclass.html).

All in all, I think you have some cleanup work to do on that query.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have also updated my question in an effort to clarify things a little more